# Matlab using system-command, very slowly under linux

Tags: linux, matlab

- I have switched from Matlab Win10 based to Matlab Linux based 64bit.
- A system command I use is

Under Win 10

```
tic
system ('curl -s \ -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: YOURAPIKEY"  \ -X GET 
"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price")';
toc
```

Under Linux

```
tic
system ('env -i curl -s \ -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: YOURAPIKEY"  \ -X GET 
"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price")';
toc
```

Problem is the execution time. Under Win10 = 2s, under Linux= 22s.
What can I do ?

Comment: There are closing parentheses missing in both `system` commands. Does this take 22s from the system shell too? You might have misconfigured the internet connection under Linux.

Comment: yes, you are right. parentnesses is missing. Have corrected it. And yes, 22s with curl in the system shell too. Internetconnection gives full 50Mbps and looks good. Can I test a misconfiguration anyhow ?

Comment: Chris, thanks. You gave me the right ideas where to look at. I simply deleted all network related software and reinstalled it. 22s are down to 1s. Issue is solve now

Comment: Glad to hear that got fixed!